# SQL Server Kerberos authentication

Tags: sql-server, kerberos

I'm trying to set SQL Server with kerberos authentication. I have these configuration files:

1. `keytab` file
2. `krb5.conf`
3. `jaas.conf`

In the `jaas.conf` file, I have added:

```
SQLJDBCDriver {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required

useKeyTab=true
debug=true;
keyTab="location of keytab"

principal="principal_name";
```

And in jvm parameter

```
-Djavax.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf -Djavax.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf
```

But when I tried to authenticate SQL Server through key tab file, I get an error:

> Unable to obtain Principal Name for authentication

I'm unable to find exact root cause, any help will be appreciated.

Even I tried to debug with issue with -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true, but not much information available

Comment: You forgot to attach your java code and the full error stack

Comment: @siggemannen

Below JDBC connection and error stack details. 

""p:url="jdbc:sqlserver://database:port;databaseName=databasename;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;" />""

Comment: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServ
erException: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:5de2624e-d8cf-44f0-b2e3-6b2c1ed9d8e1

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:5de2624e-d8cf-44f0-b2e3-6b2c1ed9d8e1

Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain Principal Name for authentication

Comment: It is resolved. Please mark it as close.